# Enforce overflow-y: hidden when element rendered outside viewport and user scrolls with middle mouse button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am rendering an element outside of the viewport. I am choosing to do so purposefully in order to avoid taking a perf. hit when transitioning the element by rendering it ahead of time. I do not wish to apply `display: none` to the element for this reason.

When the user presses their middle mouse-button down they're able to scroll down the page and see the rendered element. This is not possible with normal scroll behavior, `overflow: hidden` prevents normal scroll behavior from working.

I am aware that I could stifle the user's ability to scroll with JavaScript by using the snippet below. I would prefer not to do this. There are other elements on the page which are scrollable and I do not wish to degrade UX by limiting their actions nor overly complicate my code by checking a multitude of event targets.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.button === 1){
         event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Is it possible in modern browsers to prevent the user from scrolling down with the middle mousewheel?

You can see an example live here: https://streamus.com/testy.html

and here is the contrived example's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html {
              overflow: hidden;
              background-color: red;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .box-content {
              background-color: blue;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
            }
            .box-hiddenFooter {
              height: 50px;
              width: 200px;
              background-color: black;
                position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              transform: translateY(110%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='box-content'>
        </div>
        <div class='box-hiddenFooter'>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]